# Is there any SE site where I can ask a question about small business?

Tags: discussion

I'm opening a Very small kiosk and I have a very small question about tracking revenue, is there any SE site I can ask it on? Here? workplace? somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to our [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the following categories of questions are on-topic:

> **Sole Proprietorships**
>
> - Bookkeeping
> - Taxes as they pertain to an individual's return
> - When to incorporate to protect your work or assets

A question about tracking the revenue of your small business should be on-topic on this site, as that would fall under "Sole proprietorships - Bookkeeping" in my opinion.